# Invoking [SKProductsRequest start] hangs on iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

Encountering an issue with SKProductsRequest that is specific to iOS 4.0.  The problematic code:

```
- (void)requestProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:kLimitedDaysUpgradeProductId, kUnlimitedUpgradeProductId, nil];

    self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];

    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;

    [self.productsRequest start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
     NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}
```

When [SKProductsRequest start] is invoked, the productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: delegate method is never invoked; further, the entire app hangs and is completely unresponsive to input.  Obviously, this is a huge issue for our iOS 4.0 users as it not only breaks payments but makes the app completely unusable.

Some other things to note: this only happens on iOS 4.0; iOS 4.2, 3.x are fine.  Also: if the delegate is not set on the SKProductsRequest (i.e. comment out the line "self.productsRequest.delegate = self;"), the app doesn't hang (but of course in that case we have no way of getting the product info).  Also, the problem still reproduces with everything stripped out of the productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: callback (that method never actually gets called).  Finally, if the productIdentifiers NSSet object is initialized to an empty set, the hang doesn't occur.

Has anybody else experienced this?  Any ideas/thoughts on what could be going on here, and how we might be able to work around this?

Comment: Note: this turned out to be a an issue with a category that we implemented that overrode an NSString method and caused it to run in an infinite loop when invoked by the lower-level in-app SDK.  So, there's no generic issue here with the SDK.  Lesson learned: don't override core Cocoa methods!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried implementing –request:didFailWithError: in your delegate, and seeing if that's getting called?

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing -request:didFailWithError: as well; it's not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this today.  No response to any of the delegate methods after I made a SKProductRequest.

Everything was working fine, I didn't make any changes to the IAP code yet it broke.

Finally found the problem.  If you self reject the app, then the product ID's you made become invalid.  We resolved it by resubmitting the app and creating new ID's.  Everything started to work again after that.